# how to change timezone without affecting the saved time in currentTimeMillis()?

Tags: android, kotlin

so, let's say I want to save a data in my database and save the timestamp (date and time) for the time the data saved in database. for example in +3:00 GMT.
now the timezone changed and the saved time when I getting it is changing too but I don't want that.
I want it to show the time in that timezone not current
and I using currentTimeMillis() for getting time

it's my code of getting time

```
val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

and code for getting from database in my view holder

```
val tsLong = currentItem.timeStamp
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis` will always report in UTC regardless of the user's timezone.

I would recommend using `Instant` to store all your timestamps.  Instants can easily be converted to any timezone.  Instant has the following advantages:

1. Explicitly always in UTC/GMT timezone
2. toString() to ISO date format that is much more readable than milliseconds from the epoch

Far too often when we use milliseconds from the epoch we can't easily read them and it's ambitious if the field is seconds from the epoch or milliseconds.  using Instant removes this ambiguity and makes things easier for developers.

Comment: hi, I knew about Date, Calendar, and currentTimeMillis and I was thinking the 3rd one is the best but now I see your answer. however, I tested it and it (requires API level 26 ) and my min is 21. so I don't think that's gonna help me